Efficiently transforming non-recursive CFG into an NFA
It should be possible to rewrite a non-recursive CFG [1] as an acyclic NFA, since non-recursive CFGs represent finite languages (and thus regular a fortiori). Is there an explicit algorithm to rewrite an ε-free non-recursive grammar into an equivalent ε-free NFA? My instinct is to put the grammar into GNF [2], translate it to an NFA, then remove ε, but it seems like there should be a more straightforward way that avoids the large blowup if we assume it to be non-recursive.

Build a directed graph, with one vertex per non-terminal, and an edge $A \to B$ if there is a rule in the grammar where $A$ is on the left-hand side and $B$ appears on the right-hand side.  Since you assume the grammar is non-recursive, this graph is acyclic, i.e., a dag.
So, topologically sort the graph, and traverse the graph in reverse topologically sorted order.  When you visit a vertex $A$, you will compute an $\epsilon$-free NFA for $L(A)$, using the NFAs already computed for previously visited vertices.  This is easy using standard operations on NFAs.
For instance, suppose you visit the vertex for non-terminal $A$, and collecting all the rules with $A$ on the left-hand side gives something like $A ::= B | aDb | EF | \cdots$ (this is just an example).  Then we know $L(A) = L(B) \cup a L(D) b \cup L(E) L(F) \cup \cdots$.  Since we're traversing the graph in reverse topological order, we must already have visited $B,D,E,F$, so we already have $\epsilon$-free NFAs for $L(B), L(D), L(E), L(F)$.  So now all we need is the ability to perform the following operations on $\epsilon$-free NFAs:

Given $\epsilon$-free NFAs for languages $L_1,L_2$, compute an $\epsilon$-free NFA for their concatenation $L_1 L_2$.

Given $\epsilon$-free NFAs for languages $L_1,L_2$, compute an $\epsilon$-free NFA for their union $L_1 \cup L_2$.


Both of those can be done with standard algorithms for NFAs.

Good eye! I can tell right off the bat this will do the trick.
